# AerospikeException while writing record to Aerospike namespace hosted on Google Cloud

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, aerospike

I'm trying to write record using java AerospikeClient on Aerospike namespace hosted on Google Compute Engine. But getting following exception:

> TODO: Write user recordAerospikeException - Message: Client timeout: timeout=0 iterations=2 failedNodes=2 failedConns=0 lastNode=null
>       AerospikeException - StackTrace: com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException$Timeout: Client timeout: timeout=0 iterations=2 failedNodes=2 failedConns=0 lastNode=null
>       at com.aerospike.client.command.SyncCommand.execute(SyncCommand.java:129)
>       at com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient.put(AerospikeClient.java:299)
>       at com.aerospike.developer.training.UserService.createUser(UserService.java:126)
>       at com.aerospike.developer.training.Program.work(Program.java:120)
>       at com.aerospike.developer.training.Program.main(Program.java:67)

I have used external and internal IP of Compute Engine instance to create new AerospikeClient("compute_engine_ip",3000) but same error.
Need help to fix this error

Answer (score 4):

This exception is indicative of a connection issue between the client and server over port 3000.

Please double check your network configuration interface address and access-address settings in aerospike.conf.

[Aerospike Network Configuration](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/network/general/)

You may be able to check which IPs are being published to the clients by running the following commands on the server nodes.

```
asinfo -v services
```

and

```
asinfo -v service
```

One of the ips in the list provided from the [above command](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info/#services) should match the IP addresses configured on the client.

Its possible that the client is using an old seed server Ip address while your new cluster has different IP addresses.

It may be useful to modify your clientpolicy and set **failIfNotConnected=true** on your client to get an immediate failure in case of issue with seed server :

http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/ClientPolicy.html#failIfNotConnected